# The past of "must"

Tags: modal-verbs

[PUMPKIN HEAD](http://www.newyorker.com/fiction/features/2009/01/12/090112fi_fiction_oates?currentPage=5) (JOYCE CAROL OATES)

> He asked Hadley how long she’d lived in the house, and when she told him that she and her husband had moved there in 1988 he maintained his pained, fixed smile but did not ask about her husband. He **must** know, then, she **thought**. Someone at the co-op *has told him*.

I know that the past of *must* is *had to*. The [Oxford online dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/must) says that *must* can be used as past tense in reported speech ("she *said* she *must* be going"). But the sentence in the text is not reported speech. The modal *might* would be grammatically correct in the sentence, for *might* is the past of *may*. But can I use *must* as the past of *must*?

And I'm confused by the last sentence when the author suddenly uses the present tense ("*has told* him"). Is there a connection with the previously used *must*?

Comment: it's "must have" — not a true past tense but does the job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **He must know, then**, she thought. **Someone at the co-op has told him.**

The two marked sentences are both direct "speech", although Oates does not mark them with quotation marks—probably because they are not spoken but only thought. The *must* here therefore represents present tense.

But the past tense of *must* is not *had to*, though *had to* may substitute for it. The past tense of *must* is *must*<sup>†</sup>.

In any case, there is no justification for using either *may* or *might* here; either would completely change the meaning.

---

<sup>†</sup> Historically, in fact, *must* was the past tense of the verb *mote*, which long since disappeared from use. *Must* appears to be following in its footsteps, being more and more replaced by the more flexible quasi-modal *HAVE to*.

Comment: I said that substitution for _might_ would be grammatically correct, _may_--not. (I thought the sentence is in the past and I can't use _may_ in this case.) I agree that they would change the meaning.

Comment: If _must_ can be used as a past form, then this sentence is correct - "he avoided social engagements because he _must_ work." I changed this sentence from OD - "He avoided social engagements so that he _might_ work."

Comment: @Graduate - Either *may* or *might* would work here, because *might* (like *must*) is a past form which may bear the required present sense. *May* seems to be following the same historical trend as *mote*, as is *shall*. I suspect that two hundred years from now linguists will be writing of the Great Modal Shift the way they now write of the [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift).

Comment: @Graduate (answering your second comment) It is acceptable, and you will encounter it in formal discourse. In many contexts, however, it would be ambiguous - which is no doubt one reason why *had to* is more often employed today.